# Why is the number $e$ involved in Poisson's Distribution Formula?

Tags: calculus, probability, irrational-numbers, poisson-distribution

I know the theory about the number $e$ in compound interest, etc. But I've been really thinking about this and I don't see what the number $e$ is doing here. Many thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383113/poisson-process-derivation

Comment: There isn't the number $e$. There is a function whose derivatives equ its values at every point, whose value is $e$ at anargumebt of $1$, but the Poisson distribution does not pick out ant specific argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poisson distribution is a limit on Binominal distribution where amount of tests $n$ goes to infinity while maintaining constant gamma: $t = pn$

substitute this to the binominal equation with
$$Bin(k;n,p) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{(n-k)}$$

Here if n goes to infinity:
$$p^k  = \frac{t^k}{n^k}$$

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot \frac{t^k}{n^k} \rightarrow \frac{t^k}{k!} \cdot\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}$$

Here in the denominator are k "n"-s instead of increasing factors up to n but as $n \rightarrow \infty$, it converges to 1, so the whole

$$\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!} \rightarrow 1$$ and

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot \frac{t^k}{n^k} \rightarrow \frac{t^k}{k!} \cdot1 $$

then

$$(1-p)^{(n-k)} = \frac{\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^n}{\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^k}$$

$$\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^n \rightarrow e^{-t}$$

$$\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^k \rightarrow 1^k \rightarrow 1$$

together we will have the poisson formula

$$ \frac{t^k}{k!} e^{-t} $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Very helpful. Many thanks!

Comment: you are welcome, ask me something about probability theory if you need.  glad you could read that

Comment: I have a question about $(1-\frac{t}{n})^n \rightarrow e^{-t}$. If we replace $e$ with a constant $a > 0$ in this expression, and compute LHS/RHS, we would get $[(1-p)a^p]^n$, which would still tend to $1$ for small $p$, hence $(1-\frac{t}{n})^n \rightarrow a^{-t}$. So why does it have to be $e$ in the original expression?

Answer (score 1):

The Poisson distribution is the $n\to\infty$ limit of the Binomial distribution at fixed $\mu=np$. In terms of the probability mass function, your question is why$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^{n-k}=e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^k}{k!}.$$This [can be proved as @GoldenRatio discussed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4364414); but, in the interests of advertising some machinery that's very useful in studying both distributional families, I'll instead work in terms of the [probability-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function), which for the binomial distribution is$$\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{\mu z}{n-\mu}\right)^k=\left(1+\frac{\mu(z-1)}{n}\right)^n.$$The $n\to\infty$ limit is of course $\exp[\mu(z-1)]=\sum_{k\ge0}e^{-\mu}\frac{(\mu z)^k}{k!}$, making the probability mass $\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^k}{k!}$ for $k\in\Bbb Z^\ast$, as expected.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you recall, $e$ appears in the formula for *continuous* compounding, and more generally, it tends to rear its head in continuous-time processes.

It is thus not too surprising that $e$ appears in the Poisson distribution mass function since the [law of rare events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem) tells us the Poisson distribution is a limiting binomial distribution as the number of trials goes to infinity (holding fixed the mean).